# mySQL 64 Bit Windows Compatibility Issue

Tags: mysql, database, compatibility

I am currently having an issue with mySQL. The installation process seemed to have proceeded rather smoothly, but I run into an error whenever I attempt to start or shut down the server. The only way I can seem to start up the server is by reinstalling mySQL, and the only way I can shut it down is through the task manager.

Clicking on the "Stop (start) Server" button in the mySQL workbench gives me the following error:

Unsupported 16 bit application. 
The program or feature "\??\C:\watcom-1.3\binw\sc.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64 bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64 bit Windows compatible version is available.

I've tried downloading a 64 bit version of watcom, but this has not solved my problem. I can't seem to figure out exactly what went wrong here, and would appreciate any advice.

I've attached a link below in case you'd like to see the original error message.
http://puu.sh/nkyx4/99d4e59f74.png

Comment: I have the same error when I try to start/stop server via MySQL Workbench (6.3.10). But I'm able to do it through MySQL Notifier (1.1.7) icon in taskbar (bottom right of Windows screen)